# hadoop slave cannot connect to master:8031

Tags: hadoop

I'm a total hadoop newbee. I set up hadoop on two machines master and slave following [this tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) (I obtained the same error following [this other tutorial](https://chawlasumit.wordpress.com/2015/03/09/install-a-multi-node-hadoop-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04/)).

**Problem**: After starting dfs and yarn, the only node appearing on localhost:50070 is the master, even if the right processes are running on the master (NameNode, DataNode, SecondaryNameNode, ResourceManager) and on the slave (DataNode).

The nodemanager log of the slave reports: *INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/192.168.0.14:8031. Already tried 10 times*.

Note that:

1. I have already edited yarn-site.xml following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620949/yarn-resourcemanager-not-connecting-to-nodemanager).
2. I have disabled the firewall on the master
3. I ran *netstat -anp | grep 8031* on the master and confirmed that there are a couple of processes listening on port 8031 using tcp.

Comment: It appears that the ResourceManager is not running on your Master, can you view the logs of the ResourceManager on the master?

Comment: It is running -- sorry for not specifying it. I've edited the question.

Comment: Ok but what do the logs of the resource manager show?

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from the same problem, and these steps may help.

1. Make sure your namenodes can negotiate with your datanodes.

```sh
hadoop@namenode-01:~$ jps
8678 NameNode
9530 WebAppProxyServer
9115 ResourceManager
8940 SecondaryNameNode
9581 Jps
```

```sh
hadoop@datanode-01:~$ jps
8592 NodeManager
8715 Jps
8415 DataNode
```

2. Check your `nodemanager-datanode-01.log` from `$HADOOP_HOME/logs` reports.

```sh
INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: namenode-01/192.168.4.2:8031. Already tried 8 time(s);
```

3. Check if your `yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address` listen on `ipv6` instead of `ipv4`.

```sh
hadoop@namenode-01:~$ netstat -natp
tcp6       0      0 127.0.2.1:8088          :::*                    LISTEN      9115/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.2.1:8030          :::*                    LISTEN      9115/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.2.1:8031          :::*                    LISTEN      9115/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.2.1:8032          :::*                    LISTEN      9115/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.2.1:8033          :::*                    LISTEN      9115/java
```

4. If your `yarn addresses` listen on `ipv6`, maybe you should disable `ipv6` first.

```sh
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

5. Finally, the [default yarn addresses](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) are like this:

```
yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address   ${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8031
```

6. Check your `/ect/hosts` to avoid misconfigurations.

```sh
hadoop@namenode-01:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.2.1 namenode-01 namenode-01 (for example, this line config hostname as 127.0.2.1, delete this line)
192.168.4.2 namenode-01
192.168.4.3 datanode-01
192.168.4.4 datanode-02
192.168.4.5 datanode-03
```